# Can't create popup Menu

Tags: c++, winapi

I`m trying to create a menu programmatically but the code below fails to create the popup menu in the second menu item (neighbor of file)(in first File->new etc. everything is fine).
When I click on View it does nothing instead of show SelectAll command.

```
HMENU menu = CreateMenu();
HMENU subMenu1 = CreatePopupMenu();

AppendMenu(subMenu1,MF_STRING,IDC_MENU_NEW,_T("New"));
AppendMenu(subMenu1,MF_STRING,IDC_MENU_EXIT,_T("Exit"));

AppendMenu(menu,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)subMenu1,_T("File"));

SetMenu(dlg,menu);
HMENU menu2 = CreateMenu(); 
HMENU subMenu2 = CreatePopupMenu();

AppendMenu(menu,MF_INSERT,(UINT_PTR)menu2,_T("View"));
AppendMenu(subMenu2,MF_STRING,IDC_MENU_EXIT2,_T("Select All"));

AppendMenu(menu2,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)subMenu2,_T("View"));
```

What am I doing wrong?  Can you point me to somewhere to find the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your error is on this line of code

```
AppendMenu(menu,MF_INSERT,(UINT_PTR)menu2,_T("View"));
```

MF_INSERT is not a valid flag for AppendMenu and in fact maps to MF_ENABLED. In this case I believe you want to use MF_POPUP to insert the 'View' Sub menu.

This is how MSDN describes MF_POPUP:

> Specifies that the menu item opens a drop-down menu or submenu. The
>   uIDNewItem parameter specifies a handle to the drop-down menu or
>   submenu. This flag is used to add a menu name to a menu bar, or a menu
>   item that opens a submenu to a drop-down menu, submenu, or shortcut
>   menu.